# How to move to next line by pressing l at the end of line in VIM?

Tags: vim, macvim

Suppose my cursor is at the end of a line.

```
1  this is first line⚿
2  next line here
```

I know that I can move to the next line by hitting `j` but that's too much work if my finger is already on top of `l`. So what remapping do I need to do in order to emulate the modern behaviour of going to the beginning of the next line by pressing the right arrow or `l` at the end of a line? Similarly, how do I get to the end of the previous line by pressing `h` at the beginning of the current line?

Comment: `:help whichwrap`

Comment: I would strongly recommend against this, because mashing `l` to move around is a bit of a vim anti-pattern. This will become a crutch once it becomes muscle memory

Comment: @D.BenKnoble -- could you explain why it's an anti-pattern?  Certainly when on a machine where one hasn't set this setting, one will get behavior that's different than what one grows accustomed to, but... is there any more significant harm than that?  And, on such a machine, one can just set that setting (even if only interactively, without modifying a `.exrc`/`.vimrc`) if one wants it, no?  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @lindes pressing any of h, j, k, or l repeatedly when one w, /, C-d, _etc._, will do is an anti-pattern. It's like navigating entirely by mashing or holding arrow keys: why not use the whole suite of keyboard navigation commands? RE: crutch + muscle memory, such things have bit me before.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: I promise I'm not trying to be daft here, but bit you how?  Using arrow keys can be considered an anti-pattern because it moves your hand off the home row (though if you're mostly reading, and have your hands off the keyboard, I see no problem with reaching down to the easier-to-find-by-touch arrow keys to navigate just a little, when not otherwise typing), but how does having "move right by one character" work across line boundaries bite someone, if that's what they want it to mean?  I get it's not the default, but what's wrong with it?

Comment: @lindes Let's continue in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256286/vim-arrow-keys-crutch)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the whichwrap option:

```
:set whichwrap=lh
```

Comment: Probably because of the caveat mentioned later: `This makes "3h" different from "3dh" when the cursor crosses the end of a line.`